# How to get multiple tracks in single request from soundcloud?

Tags: soundcloud

I have several soundcloud track ids, and I want to update their information (number of plays, etc.) in a single request instead of sending a request to soundcloud for each track.
Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?ids=123,234,765,456,etc
```

source: [Fetching stats on multiple tracks from soundcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875463/fetching-stats-on-multiple-tracks-from-soundcloud)

Answer (score 0):

A track resource can only be identified by a singular id, so for updating any of the data this is best done asynchronously which allows the slowest update to be your lowest common denominator.